# access data inside a google spreadsheet nodejs

Tags: javascript, google-api, spreadsheet

I am trying to access the data inside the spreadsheet

```
 const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
 const  {promisify} = require('util');
 const creds = require('./client_secret.json');


 async function accessSpreadsheet() {

 const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1cErelgrkTYCOiEaTiFviF3M7chqMesmLBSp2rbxnFD4');
 await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
 const info  = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
 const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
 console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}`);



 }


accessSpreadsheet();
```

and it give me the error

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'jwtClient' of undefined
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have :**

1. **Client Id**
2. **client secret**
3. **refresh token**

then you can simply follow all the steps given below to access any google spreadsheet data in node JS :

**1.** **include these libraries :**

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
 const { OAuth2 } = google.auth
```

**2.**  **Setting up user**

```
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2('your client ID', 'your client Secret')

  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: 'your Refresh Token'
  });
```

**3.** **Enter range and sheet id you want to access :**

```
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth:oAuth2Client});

let result = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: 'SpreadSheet Id You Want To Access',
  range:'A1:D3' //range you can specify according to you
});
```

**4.** **now access the result object that stores the data in json format :**

```
console.log(result.data.values);
```

[image]

**you will get the data like this of above spreadsheet**

[image]